# thread causing application to crash

Tags: android, multithreading

EDIT:

just incase you read this i got the problem sorted i had gotten confused by my layouts and was editing the wrong one when i realised this all was sorted!

END EDIT!

every time i add a thread to my application it causes it to crash when the activity containing the thread is called below is the code piece containing the thread:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cam);

    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "Just Click The Magnifying Glass To Search", 5000); //creates a new pop up message that lasts for 5 seconds

    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    t.show();

    bt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button); //creates instance of button
    bt.setOnClickListener(search); //starts an on click listener for button

    preview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.myview); //creates instance of surfaceview
    previewHolder = preview.getHolder(); //creates a surfaceholder
    previewHolder.addCallback(this); //sets surfaceholder callback as the activity
    previewHolder.setType(3); //sets the type to SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS 

    th = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tv.setVisibility(0);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    th.start();
}
```

if anyone could shed some light on the situation it would be greatly appreciated

EDIT:

i have got the thread working and got it to call a method which creates Toast however when i try to modify a setting of the textview it throws an NullPointerException error

Comment: What is `tv` variable? Does it initialized? And what kind of exception do you get in logcat?

Comment: You can't update UI elements in a new thread.

Comment: What is the exception causing crash? Show what is in logcat. What is the handler? You should paste more code.

Comment: The first thing I thought when I saw "thread crash" was of was when a female I know caught a thread on her dress that unraveled things and caused a "crash" of epic proportions...but that won't help you :)

Comment: tv is my textview. and is there a way for me to set my textview visibility to 0 after 5 seconds?

Comment: 08-31 20:40:20.208: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13210): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 20:40:20.208: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(13210): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.search.visual/com.search.visual.cameraView}: java.lang.NullPointerException


thats what log cat said

Answer (score 0):

I don't see initialization of `TextView tv` in your code (`tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.id_of_textview);`). 
May be it is the cause of the problem?

To show `TextView` after 5 seconds, you can use [`handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

Comment: the initiation is outside of the on create method

Comment: Hm. And where it is? You can't initialize tv field before `onCreate()` because only in `onCreate()` you setted content view, that contains the `TextView`. If you initialize tv after `onCreate()`, then it is wrong; you can't use tv in `onCreate()` in this case. tv field will be equal to null in `onCreate()` in both cases.

Comment: i have now initialized the textview in the onCreate() and it in log cat it is still showing that tv is null what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing `TextView tv = new TextView();` then this is wrong and even if you're doing `TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);` then the layout will not be inflated before setContentView(); so you have to initialize tv in onCreate() method.

Comment: i am now initializing tv in the onCreate method and its still throwing an NullPointerException everytime